# Why don't I see the values of the integers in a returned array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    }

    int[] sortedArray = InsertionSort.sorter(myArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(sortedArray);
    }
}
```

And here is what InsertionSort.sorter looks like:

```
public static int[] sorter(int[] a) {

    return a;

}
```

And this is the output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
[I@7000a32b
[I@7000a32b
[I@7000a32b
[I@7000a32b
[I@7000a32b
[I@7000a32b
[I@7000a32b
[I@7000a32b
[I@7000a32b
[I@7000a32b
```

So what is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(sortedArray);
}
```

What is missing is the array index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(sortedArray[i]);  // note the [i]
}
```

Or (using the for-each loop):

```
for (int i: sortedArray){
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

What you were doing is print the whole array (which is not pretty in Java).

Comment: Oh sorry, I feel dumb again..

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Arrays.toString(int[])`:

```
Arrays.toString(sortedArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(sortedArray);
```

should be

```
System.out.println(sortedArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are printing the address, and not the values of the array. That's why :)